# First introduction to MVC

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc, android

I'm not sure that I fully understand this pattern. I've written a simple application that uses MVC. Please criticize my approach to the use of this pattern. For convenience, I'll post the source code of the main classes. The source code of the project can be found here: [SoundLights on GitHub](https://github.com/Leonideveloper/SoundLights/tree/master/SoundLights/src/main)

The app has one screen. Screen background might have 4 different images. To change current screen background the user is using Next and Previous buttons. Buttons Play and Pause(Stop) are used to control for the soundlights. The soundlights is matrix of colored squares (translucent squares, kind of filters).

I've used 2 different models:

- *BackgroundModel* - to process changing background
- *SoundLightsModel* - for working with the soundlights.

**SoundLightsActivity.java**

```
public class SoundLightsActivity extends Activity {

    private SoundLightsController controller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        controller = new SoundLightsControllerImpl(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        controller.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**SoundLightsController.java**

```
public interface SoundLightsController {

    void onStart();

    void onStop();

    void onDestroy();

    void onPrevious();

    void onNext();
}
```

**SoundLightsControllerImpl.java**

```
public class SoundLightsControllerImpl implements SoundLightsController {

    private final SoundLightsModel soundLightsModel;
    private final SoundLightsView view;
    private final BackgroundModel backgroundModel;

    public SoundLightsControllerImpl(Activity activity) {
        this.view = new SoundLightsViewImpl(activity, this);
        this.soundLightsModel = new SoundLightModelImpl(view);
        this.backgroundModel = new BackgroundModelImpl(view, (Context) activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        view.setInvisibleStartButton();
        view.setVisibleStopButton();
        soundLightsModel.startSoundLights();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        soundLightsModel.stopSoundLights();
        view.setVisibleStartButton();
        view.setInvisibleStopButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        soundLightsModel.stopSoundLights();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrevious() {
        backgroundModel.toPreviousBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext() {
        backgroundModel.toNextBackground();
    }
}
```

**SoundLightsView.java**

```
public interface SoundLightsView {

    void setVisibleStartButton();

    void setInvisibleStartButton();

    void setVisibleStopButton();

    void setInvisibleStopButton();

    void setColor(Matrix.Position pos, int color);

    Dimension getColorMatrixDimension();

    void setBackgroundById(int id);
}
```

**SoundLightsViewImpl.java**

```
public class SoundLightsViewImpl implements SoundLightsView {

    private final ColorMatrixView colorMatrixView;
    private final ImageButton startButton;
    private final ImageButton stopButton;

    private final SoundLightsController controller;
    private final ImageButton prevButton;
    private final ImageButton nextButton;
    private final RelativeLayout rootLayout;

    public SoundLightsViewImpl(Activity activity, SoundLightsController controller) {
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.soundlights_activity);
        this.controller = controller;
        colorMatrixView = (ColorMatrixView) activity.findViewById(R.id.colorMatrixView);
        startButton = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        prevButton = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
        nextButton = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SoundLightsViewImpl.this.controller.onStart();
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SoundLightsViewImpl.this.controller.onStop();
            }
        });

        prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SoundLightsViewImpl.this.controller.onPrevious();
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SoundLightsViewImpl.this.controller.onNext();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibleStartButton() {
        startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInvisibleStartButton() {
        startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibleStopButton() {
        stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInvisibleStopButton() {
        stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Matrix.Position pos, int color) {
        colorMatrixView.setColor(pos, color);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getColorMatrixDimension() {
        return colorMatrixView.getDimension();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundById(int id) {
        rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(id);
    }
}
```

**SoundLightsModel.java**

```
public interface SoundLightsModel {

    void startSoundLights();

    void stopSoundLights();
}
```

**SoundLightModelImpl.java**

```
public class SoundLightModelImpl implements SoundLightsModel, Runnable {

    private static final long DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 6;

    private final SoundLightsView view;
    private final PositionRandomizer positionRandomizer;
    private final ColorRandomizer colorRandomizer;
    private PeriodicallyTask singlePeriodicallyTask;

    public SoundLightModelImpl(SoundLightsView view) {
        this.view = view;
        positionRandomizer = new PositionRandomizer();
        colorRandomizer = new ColorRandomizer();
    }

    @Override
    public void startSoundLights() {
        singlePeriodicallyTask = new PeriodicallyTask();
        singlePeriodicallyTask.start(this, DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopSoundLights() {
        if (singlePeriodicallyTask != null) {
            singlePeriodicallyTask.stop();
            singlePeriodicallyTask = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        randomUpdateColor();
    }

    private synchronized void randomUpdateColor() {
        Dimension dim = view.getColorMatrixDimension();
        Matrix.Position randomPosition = positionRandomizer.randomPosition(dim);
        int randomColor = colorRandomizer.randomColor();
        view.setColor(randomPosition, randomColor);
    }
}
```

**PeriodicallyTask.java**

```
public class PeriodicallyTask {

    private boolean stopped;

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable periodicallyRunnable;

    public void start(final Runnable runnable, final long delayInMilliseconds) {
        handler = new Handler();
        stopped = false;
        periodicallyRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    runnable.run();
                    if (!stopped) {
                        handler.postDelayed(periodicallyRunnable, delayInMilliseconds);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        periodicallyRunnable.run();
    }

    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(periodicallyRunnable);
            stopped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**BackgroundModel.java**

```
public interface BackgroundModel {

    void toPreviousBackground();

    void toNextBackground();
}
```

**BackgroundModelImpl.java**

```
public class BackgroundModelImpl implements BackgroundModel {

    private static final int[] backgroundResourcesIds = new int[] {
        R.drawable.thais1, R.drawable.thais2, R.drawable.thais3, R.drawable.thais4
    };

    private final SoundLightsView view;
    private int currentIdIndex;

    public BackgroundModelImpl(SoundLightsView view, Context context) {
        this.view = view;
        currentIdIndex = 0;
        changeViewBackground();
    }

    private void changeViewBackground() {
        view.setBackgroundById(backgroundResourcesIds[currentIdIndex]);
    }

    @Override
    public void toPreviousBackground() {
        currentIdIndex = previousIdIndex();
        changeViewBackground();
    }

    private int previousIdIndex() {
        return currentIdIndex > 0
                    ? (currentIdIndex - 1)
                    : (backgroundResourcesIds.length - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void toNextBackground() {
        currentIdIndex = nextIdIndex();
        changeViewBackground();
    }

    private int nextIdIndex() {
        return currentIdIndex < backgroundResourcesIds.length - 1
                    ? (currentIdIndex + 1)
                    : 0;
    }
}
```

**Randomizer.java**

```
public class Randomizer {

    public static int randomPositiveInt() {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
        return Math.abs(random.nextInt());
    }
}
```

**ColorRandomizer.java**

```
public class ColorRandomizer {

    private static final int MAX_ALPHA_COMPONENT = 45;

    public static int randomColor() {
        int alpha = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % MAX_ALPHA_COMPONENT;
        int red = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % 256;
        int green = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % 256;
        int blue = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % 256;
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }
}
```

**PositionRandomizer.java**

```
public class PositionRandomizer {

    private Matrix.Position prevPosition = null;

    public Matrix.Position randomPosition(Dimension dim) {
        int row = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % dim.rows;
        int column = Randomizer.randomPositiveInt() % dim.columns;
        return new Matrix.Position(row, column);
    }

    private synchronized Matrix.Position nextPosition(Dimension dim) {
        Matrix.Position next =
                prevPosition == null
                        ? new Matrix.Position(0, 0)
                        : nextPosition(prevPosition, dim);
        prevPosition = next;
        return next;
    }

    private Matrix.Position nextPosition(Matrix.Position prevPosition, Dimension dim) {
        int column = prevPosition.column + 1;
        int row = prevPosition.row;
        if (column >= dim.columns) {
            column = 0;
            ++row;
            if (row >= dim.rows) {
                row = 0;
            }
        }
        return new Matrix.Position(row, column);
    }
}
```

**ColorMatrixView.java**

```
public class ColorMatrixView extends FrameLayout {
    private static final int DEF_ROWS = 3;
    private static final int DEF_COLUMNS = 2;
    private static final int DEF_COLOR = Color.argb(35, 100, 150, 69);

    private int rows = DEF_ROWS;
    private int columns = DEF_COLUMNS;
    private int initColor = DEF_COLOR;
    private Context context;
    private Matrix<View> matrixElements;

    public ColorMatrixView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ColorMatrixView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processAttributes(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ColorMatrixView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        processAttributes(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void processAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                            attrs, R.styleable.ColorMatrixView);
        final int N = typedArray.getIndexCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            int index = typedArray.getIndex(i);
            switch (index)
            {
                case R.styleable.ColorMatrixView_rows:
                    this.rows = typedArray.getInt(index, DEF_ROWS);
                    break;

                case R.styleable.ColorMatrixView_columns:
                    this.columns = typedArray.getInt(index, DEF_COLUMNS);
                    break;

                case R.styleable.ColorMatrixView_initColor:
                    this.initColor = typedArray.getColor(index, DEF_COLOR);
                    break;
            }
        }
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LinearLayout verticalLayout = prepareLinearLayout(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        matrixElements = new Matrix<View>(rows, columns);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
            LinearLayout rowLayout = prepareLinearLayout(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
                View element = prepareColorMatrixElement();
                rowLayout.addView(element);
                matrixElements.set(new Matrix.Position(row, column), element);
            }
            verticalLayout.addView(rowLayout);
        }
        addView(verticalLayout);
    }

    private LinearLayout prepareLinearLayout(int orientation) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setOrientation(orientation);
        addParams(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    private View prepareColorMatrixElement() {
        View tableElement = new ImageView(context);
        addParams(tableElement);
        tableElement.setBackgroundColor(initColor);
        return tableElement;
    }

    private void addParams(View view) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1.0f);
        view.setLayoutParams(param);
    }

    public void setColor(Matrix.Position pos, int color) {
        setColor(pos.row, pos.column, color);
    }

    public void setColor(int row, int column, int color) {
        View element = matrixElements.get(row, column);
        element.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    public Dimension getDimension() {
        return new Dimension(rows, columns);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only skimmed through, and all I could find is a `bool stopped` which I would have called `bool isStopped`, although `stopped` is a fairly unambiguous, clear name - as is the rest of this code.

Oh, and maybe the `256` hard-coded into your `ColorRandomizer` could be a constant.

Naming is crystal-clear and consistent, indentation is perfect; simple, neat, ...nothing to add.

---

As for MVC, well I can't talk about Java specifics (never wrote a line of Java), but *design patterns* are a mean of communication, so when you say "I do X in my *controller*", fellow programmers know what you're talking about.

- The **Model** contains *data that the View needs to render*.
- The **View** contains your markup.
- The **Controller** receives a request and responds with a *view*.

Given that, I believe your *model* should know nothing about a *view* - rather, it's the opposite: the *view* needs to know about the *model*. Now I'd love to see another answer from an actual Java developer, because I've only done MVC with ASP.NET in C#, so I'm hoping for this to be confirmed or corrected :)

Comment: upvote, but I think it's important to mention that the view should only know the model through the controller. So for someone who doesn't know about MVC it's important to mention that it's the controller that communicate between the model and the view

Comment: I don't agree with the renaming suggestion (`isStopped` should be the name for the getter, if there should be one, which returns `stopped`), otherwise I totally agree.

Comment: @user1021726 Although theoretically correct, I myself often implement it so that the view actually knows about the model. And I've seen many other examples that seems to do it that way. (This is just my opinion though)

Comment: In ASP.NET/MVC the view *explicitly* knows about the model.

Comment: @user1021726 [People don't always agree about the MVC concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742018/in-ideal-mvc-should-the-view-know-the-model) (also read the comments)